# "Ternary logic" for returned value: foo, bar or error

Tags: json, batch-processing, jq

I've got two different JSON structures to retrieve a specific object value from, basically something like this

```
{
    "one": {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    }
}
```

and another like that

```
{
    "two": {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "qux"
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to return the `bar` value in both cases plus an additional return variant `error` in case neither case 1 - `baz` - nor case 2 - `qux` - matches anything (i.e. matches `null`).

Is there a simple way to do that with just jq 1.6?

**Update:**
Here are snippets of actual JSON files:

```
/* manifest.json, variant A */
{
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "{95ad7b39-5d3e-1029-7285-9455bcf665c0}",
            "strict_min_version": "68.0"
        }
    }
}

/* manifest.json, variant B */
{
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "j30D-3YFPUvj9u9izFoPSjlNYZfF22xS@foobar",
            "strict_min_version": "53.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I need the `id` values (*gecko.id so to speak) or `error` if there is none:

```
{95ad7b39-5d3e-1029-7285-9455bcf665c0}
j30D-3YFPUvj9u9izFoPSjlNYZfF22xS@foobar
error
```

Comment: Yes, however the values `baz` and `qux` may differ. The paths, i.e. these two variants, are known to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(.. | objects | select(has("id"))).id // "error"
```

This will work with multiple files and files containing multiple separate entities.

<sub>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/y14Dmo-0XF)</sub>

Comment: This does what I was looking for, moreover it respects the `*gecko.id` kind of hierarchy, thanks alot.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a filter as below that could work with both your sample JSON content provided

```
jq '.. | if type == "object" and has("id") then .id else empty end'
```

See them live [jqplay - VariantA](https://jqplay.org/s/NMilHWWc33) and [jqplay - VariantB](https://jqplay.org/s/BIY2qgj4CW)

**Note**: This only gets the value of `.id` when it is present, see others answers ([oguz ismail's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57573926/5291015)) for displaying `error` when the object does not contain the required field.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the `?` "error suppression" and `//` "alternative` operators :

```
jq -n --slurpfile variantA yourFirstFile --slurpfile variantB yourSecondFile \
'(
  ($variantA[0].browser_specific_settings.gecko.id)?, 
  ($variantB[0].applications.gecko.id)?
) // "error"'
```

This will output the id from the first file and/or the id from the second file if any of the two exist, avoiding to raise errors when they don't, and output `error` instead if none of them can be found.

The command can be shortened as follows if it makes sense in your context :

```
jq -n --slurpfile variantA yourFirstFile --slurpfile variantB yourSecondFile \
'(($variantA[0].browser_specific_settings, $variantB[0].applications) | .gecko.id)? // "error"'
```

Comment: @oguzismail regarding slurpfile : in my understanding OP wants to return one key and/or the other if any of the two exist, and "error" if they don't, which if we want to implement in `jq` requires reading both files at once. regarding the hardcoded keys : I'm not sure whether OP wants to search the `.gecko.id` path for any object, in which case you're correct and `..` is the way to go, or for multiple varying specific objects, in which case hardcoding their path makes sense. I see how you could come to your understanding, but I feel like OP's question leaves room for my interpretation too.

Comment: Regarding the slurpfile part : I hadn't considered you could pass multiple files as simple parameter and have `jq` work on their merged content as in your answer. Still depends on whether OP wants to work on specific files and their associated specific keys, if that's not the case my answer is needlessly complicated. I'll edit if OP clarifies

Comment: I'll stick to the approach above as jq runs in a script which processes a random xpi file as parameter, so I have one file to parse with jq at once. However, this variant looks interesting as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the id values (*gecko.id so to speak) or error if there is none:

In accordance with your notation `"*gecko.id"`, here are two solutions, the first interpreting the "*" as a single unknown key (or index), the second interpreting it (more or less) as any number of keys or indices:

```
.[] | .gecko.id // "error"
```

```
.. | objects | select(has("gecko")) | (.gecko.id // "error")
```

If you don't really care about whether there's a "gecko" key, you might wish to consider:

```
first(.. | objects | select(has("id")).id ) // "error"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

for example:

```
var value;
if(applications.gecko.hasOwnProperty('id'))
   value = applications.gecko.id;
else
   value = 'error';
```

Comment: OP is looking for a solution using jq, not JavaScript.